# Windows USB disconect sound

Tags: windows-10, usb

Windows 10
I've been hearing the USB connect/disconnect sound, even though I'm not touching any of my USB devices. I downloaded EventGhost, that pointed that the device was System.DeviceAttached [u'\\?\USB#VID_045E&PID_02E6#520201#{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed}']

And I have no idea of what is that device.

Answer (score 0):

#### I have no idea of what is that device.

> ```
> '\\?\USB#VID_045E&PID_02E6#520201#{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed}'
> ```

From [USB\VID_045E - Microsoft Corp. | Device Hunt](https://devicehunt.com/view/type/usb/vendor/045E) it seems to be a Wireless XBox Controller Dongle

> [image]